# Add listt to a dataframe inside a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `full_data` with thousands of columns. These columns have values for city population at different years. The column names could be: (`London_2022`, `London_2032`, `HonKong_2022`, `HonKong_2032`).

And I have a list of vectors, where each vector is a concatenation of a list of cities:

```
list_cities <- list(List_Cities_1, List_Cities_2)
```

I want to develope a for loop that allows me to create another list. Each element of the list would be a dataframe where I have the corresponding columns from `full_data` for each list.

This is what I tried:

```
df_list <- list()

for (list in list_cities) {
  # Select the columns of interest
  selected_cols <- select(full_data, starts_with(paste0(list, "_")))
  # Append the dataframe into the list
  df_list[[list]] <- selected_cols
}
```

However, this gives me the following error:
`Error in`[[<-`(`*tmp*`, signature, value = selected_cols) :  no such index at level 1` 
Not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make a [reproducible example](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=r+reproducible+example&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: Rather than use a for loop, I would suggest `lapply(list_cities, function(cities) select(full_data, starts_with(paste0(cities, "_"))))`

Comment: Or `purrr::map()`: `map(list_cities, \(city) select(full_data, starts_with(paste0(city, "_"))))`.  (Or even just `starts_with(city)`...)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against using the function name `list` as your looping iterator - it makes the code more confusing to read.

I think your main problem is that in each iteration `list` is a vector of city names with length > 1, then `df_[[list]]` won't work because `[[` can only be used with a length 1 index. Instead, let's use a numeric index for iteration, which is often simpler.

I can't be sure without seeing sample data/data structures, but I think this should work:

```
list_cities <- list(List_Cities_1, List_Cities_2)

df_list = list()
for (i in seq_along(list_cities)) {
  # Select the columns of interest
  df_list[[i]] <- select(full_data, starts_with(list_cities[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe your desired output further? In the code below I assume you want all years of a given city as an element of the resulting list. My gut feeling is that creating various lists makes your life harder rather than easier in this case. Instead of loops, R provides various vectorized functions already.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define dummy data
df <- tribble(
  ~London_2022, ~London_2032, ~HonKong_2022, ~HonKong_2032,
  runif(1), runif(1), runif(1), runif(1)
)

# pivot longer
df <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = "name",
    values_to = "value"
  )

# extract city names for grouping
df <- df |> 
  mutate(city = str_extract(name, "[^_]+"))

# split dataframe into list of dataframes
df |> 
  nest(.by = city) |> 
  pull(data)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   name        value
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 London_2022 0.600
#> 2 London_2032 0.897
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   name         value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 HonKong_2022 0.265
#> 2 HonKong_2032 0.190
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>